# Captions in double pages in hvfloat package

Tags: floats, captions

I am trying to use [`hvfloat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat), to typeset a `fulldoublepage` float, as described on page 72 of its [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hvfloat/doc/hvfloat.pdf).

It does not work as I expected, however, in that it appears to insert extra blank pages before and after the first portion of the figure. It also does not correctly typeset the full caption as expected, as shown in the example.

What am I doing wrong or is there perhaps something wrong with the package, in modern LaTeX environments?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hvfloat}
\begin{document}

\chapter{1}
        
        
         \blindtext[1]
         
                  
\hvFloat[%
     doubleFULLPAGE,
     capPos=before]
     {figure}{\includegraphics
     [height=\paperheight,width=2\paperwidth,
keepaspectratio=false]
{example-image-b}}% or any other image
     [Caption short]{
     Caption  that should be at the bottom of the preceding page as per hvflat manual p. 72.}{fig:3}    
         
         
                      \blindtext[2]
         
\end{document}
```

Comment: After further investigation, I see what you mean. I'm also not sure what is going on.